# Is it possible to vertically align in the vscode debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to get neatly aligned output in a vertical layout?

I don't want that ..

Comment: Switch to a monospaced font (where all symbols have the same width).

Comment: in VSC you can set different fonts for editor, terminal, and UI(??)

Comment: switch to fixed width font ?!